# gerrit query REST API vs. gerrit query API

Tags: gerrit

I found we can use gerrit query api to query as below:

```
ssh -p 29418 gerrit.review.com gerrit query --format JSON --current-patch-set status:open MY-JIRA
```

But I found another python module pygerrit2 as well, I guess this module is using REST API, which one is more better for user? How can I translate above command to REST API if possible!

I try below but doesn't work:

```
mylst = rest.get("/changes/?q=status:open%20current-patch-set%20{}".format(jira))
```

Comment: Have a look at this api: https://python-gerrit-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: It doesn't answer your questions but it is more complete and works pretty well